# A possible characterization of Euclidean geometry via the curvature of the Median-submanifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Is there a  Riemannian metric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with inducing  distance
$d$ which is  not isometric  to the  standard metric  but satisfy the  property  quoted bellow?

> For  every two  distinct  points  $p,q\in \mathbb{R}^2$, the  locus  of  all  points $z$  with $d(z,p)=d(z,q)$ is  a geodesic.

As a higher dimensional version:

Is there a  Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is  not isometric  to the  standard metric  but satisfy the  property  quoted bellow?

> > For  every two   distinct points $p,q\in \mathbb{R}^3$, the  locus  of  all  points $z$  with $d(z,p)=d(z,q)$ is  a 2 dimensional  submanifold with constant sectional curvature?

## Edit:

According to the comment of  Willie  Wong, I realized that  the  previous version of the  question should be  reconstructed. So  I  present the  question as follows:

> Assume  that we  have  a complete Riemannian  metric  on $\mathbb{R}^n$  which satisfies the  following property:  For  every $2$ points $p,q$, the  locus  of  all points $\{z\mid d(z,p)=d(z,q)\}$ is  a  codimension- $1$  smooth submanifold  which is  a totally geodesic  submanifold. Does  this  imply that the  metric  is  isometric  to either Hyperbolic  space  or  the  Euclidean space?

Comment: Aren't the hyperbolic metric and the sphere metric examples?

Comment: Also, I don't get how you related the two questions. The higher dimensional generalization of geodesic curvature should not be sectional curvature, but either mean curvature or the entire second fundamental form (in which case the submanifold is totally geodesic).

Comment: @WillieWong  yes thank you. These geometries gives us  models not isometric to the Euclidean metric. But does the property under first question implies that the curvature is constant?Or in higher domension, assuming that  the median submanifold is totally geodesic, can we conclude that the curvature is constant?Thanks for your revision of the second question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the affirmative, even in the more general setting of general (pseudo)-Riemannian manifolds.

In the Riemannian case this is a theorem due to Busemann. Consider a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. The set $\Sigma_{p,q}$ consisting of all points equidistant from $p$ and $q$ on a Riemannian manifold is called the *bisector* of $\{p,q\}$. Busemann's theorem states that if $\Sigma_{p,q}$ are totally geodesic for any $\{p,q\}$, then $(M,g)$ has constant sectional curvature.

A generalization was proven by Beem for pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. The definition of "distance" and "bisector" requires a bit of care. Both are only defined within "simple convex neighborhoods", and the bisector is only a submanifold when $p$ and $q$ is not joined by a null geodesic. It turns out that this "local" distance function and "local" bisector, for pairs of points that are time-like or space-like separated, is enough to imply Busemann's theorem.

---

#### References

*Busemann, H.*, The geometry of geodesics, Pure and applied Mathematics, 6. New York: Academic Press, Inc. X, 422 p. (1955). [ZBL0112.37002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0112.37002).

*Beem, John K.*, [**Pseudo-Riemannian manifolds with totally geodesic bisectors**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2039818), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 49, 212-215 (1975). [ZBL0301.53026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0301.53026).

Comment: I really thank you Willie for your very perfect and interesting answer.